Cannot install uuid-dev:arm64 on Jammy amd64 when using snapcraft
I am trying to build gadget snap for arm64 platform, where I get message:
Cannot find package listed in 'build-packages': uuid-dev:arm64
I have tride to add:
package-repositories:
  - type: apt
    url: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
    suites: [jammy]
    components: [main, universe]
    architectures: [arm64]
    key-id: F6ECB3762474EDA9D21B7022871920D1991BC93C
    key-server: keyserver.ubuntu.com

with no success.
